# Obtaining Source Code From C Code Compiled with Debugging Options

Tags: c, debugging, compilation

I have heard that it is possible to obtain the source code from an executable if it was compiled with debugging (-g) enabled. Is this true? If so, how would one go about doing it?

Comment: It would be like unscrambling an egg.

Comment: There are C decompilers, google it. And if you have debugging enabled, they can get the original variable names.

Comment: You may be able to get symbols but the original source code, probably not.

Comment: Most debug formats usually have references to the name of the source file, line numbers etc but usually do not encode the actual source. In the case where the source files are not present the references in the debug information are pretty useless.

Comment: when compiling/linking the code, using '-g' (or for gcc '-ggdb') will not keep the original source code.   when using gdb the actual source code file(s) must be visible to the gdb utility. (usually in the same directory)   Then, in gdb the actual source code can be displayed.   In other debuggers, quite often the source code and resulting assembly can be displayed intermixed. (do not enable optimization or the source code and assembly will not align/match).  The CCS debugger is such a tool for interleaved debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You can't restore source code from binary executable. 
You can use decompiler like [REC Studio](http://www.backerstreet.com/rec/rec.htm) or [Boomerang](http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/) to convert dissassembled binary into c code, but this code won't be anything like initial code you compiled. It would be more like assembly written in C syntax. If your application is complicated, it probably won't be able to compile. Debugging symbols can help, but not a lot. Many information is lost during compilation and can't be restored.

Answer (score 0):

You can use objdump utility.
objdump has option '-S' which also provides source code and respective assembly code. This also helps in debugging crashes (segmentation faults).

e.g. I have copied the code snippet and its objdump (just for example).
Only the main() of objdump is copied, it contains other info too.

Steps to do : 
Suppose you wrote code in file temp.c .

```
gcc -g temp.c -o temp
objdump -DS temp > temp.dump

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, *b;
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    printf("a=%d *b=%d", a, *b);
    return 0;
}

0804841d <main>:
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 804841d:       55                      push   %ebp
 804841e:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048420:       83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 8048423:       83 ec 20                sub    $0x20,%esp
        int a, *b;
        a = 0;
 8048426:       c7 44 24 18 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x18(%esp)
 804842d:       00
        b = 0;
 804842e:       c7 44 24 1c 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x1c(%esp)
 8048435:       00
        printf("a=%d *b=%d", a, *b);
 8048436:       8b 44 24 1c             mov    0x1c(%esp),%eax
 804843a:       8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax
 804843c:       89 44 24 08             mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
 8048440:       8b 44 24 18             mov    0x18(%esp),%eax
 8048444:       89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 8048448:       c7 04 24 f0 84 04 08    movl   $0x80484f0,(%esp)
 804844f:       e8 9c fe ff ff          call   80482f0 <printf@plt>
        return 0;
 8048454:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
}
 8048459:       c9                      leave
 804845a:       c3                      ret
 804845b:       66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 804845d:       66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 804845f:       90                      nop
```

Comment: the source code file needs to be visible to the objdump utility for this to work